# Update column data using data patch Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, backend, magento2.4.4

In Magento Database, by default we have company & company_address table if we are using B2B.

In both the tables we have 'telephone' field.
I want to create a data patch which will remove strings/paranthesis from all data of 'telephone' field.

Can someone guide me how to update column value using data patch in Magento 2 for Company module.
Someone please guide me on what's wrong in the code I am sharing that I am using-

```
<?php
namespace Test\CompanyAddressCustomTelephone\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Company\Api\CompanyRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class ReformatTelephoneField implements DataPatchInterface
{
   /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
   private $moduleDataSetup;

   /** @var EavSetupFactory */
   private $eavSetupFactory;
   
   public CompanyRepositoryInterface $companyRepository;

   /**
    * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    */
   public function __construct(
       ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
       EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
       CompanyRepositoryInterface $companyRepository,
       SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
   ) {
       $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
       $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
       $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function apply()
   {   
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $setup = $this->moduleDataSetup;
    
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $companyList = $this->companyRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

        foreach($companyList as $company) {
            $telephone = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $company->getTelephone());
        }

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->update($this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('company'), ['telephone' => $telephone]);     
        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();     
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public static function getDependencies()
   {
       return [];
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function getAliases()
   {
       return [];
   }

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   public static function getVersion()
   {
      return '2.0.0';
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot of table what values(strings/paranthesis) you are getting.

Comment: This is the proper syntax, please try this:
$telephone = preg_replace("/\(|\)/", "", $telephone);

Comment: Yup, I had this format with me. But the confusion was with the way to update. But now it's resolved. Thanks for the input still